# snappy Bézier curves

Tags: c#, math, interpolation, shapes, bezier

The more control points on a Bézier curve the less near any given control point the curve reaches.

For example a 2 point (linier) curve reaches both control points. A 3 point (quadratic) curve forms an arc, between the three points, this is ideal for me, it's not following the line exactly, as then it wouldn't be a curve, there is however a strong visual relationship between the control points and the line.

With a 4 point (cubic) curve with control points in a zig-zag however the resultant line is much more straight. Extended to use 100 control points in a zig-zag the curve is almost completly straight.

To stay with the zig-zag example, one way to form the curve I'm looking for, which in this case would look like a less aggressively smoothed zig-zag than an 100 control point Bézier curve would produce, would be to break the shape into many small 3 point Bézier curves, interpolating between them at the ends.

Is there C#, pseudo-code or even just more information in a simple form available to do this more complicated Bézier curve related task?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve - there is a pretty nice explanation of how bezier curves are contructed. Just look at the section where different curve orders are applied

Comment: Showing well what the problem is for me. Both of the following examples have high curve orders and in both cases the line is not followed very precisely, the curve is too far away from the straight lines formed by connecting the curves controll points too much of the time, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bezier_4_big.gif, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BezierCurve.gif. This is less of an issue for low order curves, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bezier_2_big.gif, however they are simple curves with too few control points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something very easy to implement is to build the curve using quadratic bezier arcs

[image]

You basically use midpoints between source vertices as start/stop of each arc and source vertices as the control point for the arc. This choice guarantees continuity of the tangent and leaves a lot of control on the curve shape.

Also you can easily get sharp corners by using two consecutive source vertices with the same coordinates.